# Change monitor resolution with Xorg fails

Tags: 18.04, display-resolution, xrandr, ubuntu-studio

I'm using Xorg (not Wayland) and I have tried to change the resolution of my monitor to 2560x1440 and I get the error crtc 0, and I have followed the recommendations for other similar cases without success.

Comment: Are you running wayland or xorg?  What command did you run ? Please post the command and output

Comment: As Panther requested please [edit] your post to include  your command and the full error that you received. It would also be very helpful if you were to cite the recommendations that you tried. Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: serikame@ZYX:~$ cvt 2560 1440 60
# 2560x1440 59.96 Hz (CVT 3.69M9) hsync: 89.52 kHz; pclk: 312.25 MHz
Modeline "2560x1440_60.00"  312.25  2560 2752 3024 3488  1440 1443 1448 1493 -hsync +vsync
serikame@ZYX:~$ xrandr --newmode "2560x1440_60.00"  312.25  2560 2752 3024 3488  1440 1443 1448 1493 -hsync +vsync
serikame@ZYX:~$ xrandr --addmode DisplayPort-1 2560x1440_60.00
serikame@ZYX:~$ xrandr --output DisplayPort-1 --mode 2560x1440_60.00
xrandr: Configure crtc 0 failed

Comment: Please click on the edit link above at left, and paste in your results, as the comments box loses all formatting and makes it difficult to read what you found.